# Prove that whenever L is a regular language so is HasPrefix(L)

Tags: algorithms, regular-language

For a language $L$ over an alphabet $\Sigma$, deﬁne the language $\operatorname{HasPrefix}(L)$ as follows: $$\operatorname{HasPrefix}(L) = \{xy\mid x,y \in\Sigma^*, x \in L, xy \in L, |y|> 0\}$$
Note the last condition, which requires that y be nonempty.

I want to prove that if $L$ is regular, then so is $\operatorname{HasPrefix}(L)$.

Any suggestions on how to approach this? I want to prove it by making DFAs for the language L and HasPrefix(L) to show that they're both regular.

Comment: Several characters seemed to be missing from your formula. I have attempted to edit to put them in. Please indicate if the result is not what you intended to write.

Comment: I apologize, it's a typo and I fixed it. @Ojas thank you! But I would like to prove it by constructing DFAs to show that both are regular. Any tips on how to prove it using construction?

Comment: @HenningMakholm thank you, it's correct now

Comment: Hint: Take a DFA for $L$ and split each state into two to keep track of whether you've already seen an accepting state.

Comment: @Ojas That regex doesn't describe HasPrefix.  For one thing, HasPrefix(L) is always a sublanguage of $L$, which $r\Sigma^*$ won't be.

Comment: @ErickWong I missed the part $ xy \in L$. Thanks for pointing it out!
To the OP : My previous comment was wrong, so deleting it. Sorry!

Comment: Thank you for the help but I guess I dont understand what HasPrefix(L) is actually doing. Can someone give me an example of what HasPrefix(L) would look like if L = {cat, dog, mouse, bird}?

Comment: Here's a hint based on @HenningMakholm's idea : Use 2 DFA's of L for the language HasPrefix(L). Move along one of the DFA's and when you reach the accepting state of that DFA, start moving on the 2nd DFA. If at the end of the string, you are on the accepting state of the 2nd DFA, then the string is in HasPrefix(L). 
PS: Again, correct me if I am wrong. I am also not so well versed in regular languages.

Comment: @deryl: If you don't even understand _what_ the problem is asking you to prove it is **ESSENTIAL** that you reveal that in the question itself. Otherwise you will get answers that assume that you understand _what_ it asks for but just need help _doing_ it.

Comment: HasPrefix(L) consists of all words from $L$ that have a proper prefix that is also in $L$. If $L$ is {"cat", "dog", "mouse", "bird"}, then HasPrefix(L) is empty! It can't contain "cat" because neither "" nor "c" nor "ca" is in L, and it can't contain "cats" either because "cats" is not in L even though its prefix "cat" is.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I apologize, I thought I knew what the question was asking for. So just for clarification, if L = {cat, catdog, fish, fishdog} then Hasprefix(L) = {catdog, fishdog} right?

Comment: @deryl: Right. ${}$

Comment: Great I think i got a pretty good idea of what to do. Thanks guys